# Responsivness of threads related to user

Tags: java, performance, oracle, jdbc

Our Java application runs frequently heavy databases queries. As Java process and Oracle process run on the same computer, these heavy queries may consume so much of CPU or IO that important applicative threads i.e. user requests, become unresponsive.

I'm looking for a solution to prioritize transactions (or connections or connection pools) in Oracle. I am aware of Oracle's Resource Manager feature, but we don't have license to use it.

If the prioritization is not possible can transactions be paused or even killed in the middle?

We are running on Linux, J2EE, hibernate / sql

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents worth: Try to control priorities at the Java (i.e. application) level rather than relying on Oracle.  This could be done using a `PriorityBlockingQueue` from which threads consume database requests.

Comment: A priority queue is a data structure used for rendering the 'highest valued' element -- nothing to do with thread priorities / scheduling.

Comment: @seand: You're thinking of PriorityQueue; I'm talking about PriorityBlockingQueue, which is designed precisely for multi-threaded applications and forms part of the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: This is a good answer, but is not a solution. When the application queries Oracle with a heavy query it does not know whether there will be user requests in the middle the processing or not

Answer (score 1):

I'm trusting that you're not attempting do these DB operations from the UI's event dispatch thread :)

You might try messing with thread priorities; use a lower priority on the DB threads so the UI remains responsive.  However this might not be effective and may have other issues such as priority inversion.

Another idea is to put short sleeps in a DB thread, or try yield() every so often.  These should be done outside DB transactions so that you don't block other concurrent DB clients.

Comment: Applicative CPU consuming threads will behave exactly this way, however I don't know what to do with UI requests that happen in the middle of heavy query processing by Oracle

Comment: It's often recommended that DB's live on its own box.  Do you know what exactly in Oracle is chewing up the CPU?  Perhaps there's something you can do on that side.  You *might* be able to reduce the thread priority of the Oracle processes but that can be iffy.

Answer (score 0):

On the Oracle side, I would definitely *not* recommend messing with Oracle server process priorities.  The main reason is, at any given moment, an Oracle process may be holding a lock or latch on some element of the SGA.  If you lower the priority of a process, and it's holding locks and/or latches, you could end up impacting the performance of other Oracle server processes, as they queue up behind the lock/latch holder, which is low priority, and now can't get any CPU.

Oracle itself does allow for certain background processes to run at higher priority, but that's by design, and functionality that's built-in to Oracle.  I wouldn't mess with priorities of individual server processes.

Finally, I'd really look at the feasibility of moving the Java application code to a different server.  That way, Oracle and Java aren't competing for what sounds like a scarce resource.

Hope that helps.